# Pushlish TestNG results in TFS

Tags: java, tfs, testng, tfsbuild

We have created a Maven project and automated test scripts using Selenium, Java and TestNG framework.

The code is checked in tfs using TEE plugin and we are able to create maven build in tfs. Now we need to publish the results of the test scripts in TFS.

Please advise how could we publish the results in TFS and generate reports.

Comment: Which build system are you using? XAML or vNext?

Answer (score 1):

Generate a custom report from TestNG is pretty easy: just implements your own `IReporter`. See the related documentation: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging

Now, you have to find what is the best way for sending test reports to TFS.
It could be by generating a specific file or by using an API like https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/results#add-test-results-to-a-test-run