# TFS and TestNG - Possible to Execute TestNG test(s) within TFS2015?

Tags: java, maven, tfs, testng

TFS and TestNG - Possible to Execute TestNG test(s) within TFS2015?

1. I have uploaded a Java Maven project to a Repo in my instance of TFS.
2. My java Maven project comprises of TestNG Test / classes
3. I can see that there is a Maven plugin within the TFS which also has a JUnit link.

**4. I cant see any option to enable me to execute TestNG tests within the TFS, is it even possible?**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's able to use Maven task to build a Java application or test the application including TestNG test.  Detail steps please refer this tutorial: [Get started testing Java applications with Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/continuous-testing/getting-started/continuous-test-java)

For test result report just follow *juherr*'s reply in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39275652/pushlish-testng-results-in-tfs/39279029#39279029).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should be able to run your TestNG tests.

I think its eventually going to be Maven that is going to be executing your tests.

Maven makes use of surefire-plugin to basically execute your tests. For TestNG here's two of executing tests via surefire-plugin

- If your test matches the default pattern "**/Test*.java", "**/*Test.java", "**/*TestCase.java" (See [here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire-archives/surefire-2.17/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html))
- Create a suite xml file for TestNG (See [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml)) and have surefire plugin refer to it (see [here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire-archives/surefire-2.17/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html)).

Comment: thanks, do you know whether its possible to then feed tests results from the generated reports into the TFS results dashboard?

Comment: No I have not done something like that. You can perhaps see if http://stackoverflow.com/a/39279029/679824 answers that part.

On a side note, please help accept my answer, if it helped you with your question.