# Selenium Java + TestNG integration with TFS

Tags: java, tfs

I have my selenium code in Java with TestNg framework (used Eclipse as code editor), but now I need to integrate it in TFS. I am very new to TFS but I have seen many ppl told it is possible so if somebody can help me with exact steps from starting it would be really helpful. If some hidden tips and tricks also , any body can suggest for smooth integration please do so. Thanks in advance for your time!!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is setting up your environment, both local and build server. You'd better to make they are some as each other, which could significantly reduce build issue/error.

For your local develop environment, please use [Visual Studio Team Explorer Everywhere for Eclipse (VSTS and TFS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/java/download-eclipse-plug-in?view=vsts) which is a plug-in for **Eclipse** that enables you to work with Team Foundation Server (TFS) and Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) using both Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC) and Git version control systems.

Since you are new to TFS, suggest you first go through the build and deploy pipeline of JAVA projects with TFS. -- [Working with Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) and Java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/java/?view=vsts)

About Selenium and test, please take a look at below tutorials:

- [*Testing Java applications with VSTS*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/test/continuous-test-java?toc=/vsts/java/toc.json&bc=/vsts/java/breadcrumb/toc.json&view=vsts)
- [Selenium Java Integration with Team Foundation Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40912499/selenium-java-integration-with-team-foundation-server?rq=1)
- *[Get started with Selenium testing in a CD pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/test/continuous-test-selenium?view=vsts)*

Comment: 1)setting up your environment, both local and build server--- can you please elaborate a little.    2)  Visual Studio Team Explorer Everywhere for Eclipse --- > by using this I can store my test Project in TFS repository and later I have to add this into my build definition. So, for build definition what all steps I need to take?   and which build definition - there are many options .  Also, do i need to install any extension in TFS so it supports my Java tests?

Comment: @Samira Sorry for the later reply. For point 1) I just mean usually we will do our tests（Selenium Java + TestNG in your case）locally, if test run successfully, then we will move it to TFS server side. It's better to make the environment of TFS build server run the same as your local environment. This will narrow down the build issue occurs.

Comment: @Samira About 2 what all steps I need to take? Either choose a build emplate and customize later as your need, or directly select a empty process. The [TFS Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vsts) has numerous plugins - the annswer I linked above shows how to use the Maven plugin to run TestNG tests. Maven plugin is installed by default, you will not have to install it manually again. Suggest you go through the tutorials  above and could also take a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42926119/tfs-and-testng-possible-to-execute-testng-tests-within-tfs2015